# Craigslist or Kijiji - Is it possible to extract posters email address?

Tags: craigslist

Hi and thanks in advance for helping me with my question.

Is it possible to write a script that would extract the following information when provided with a craigslist or kiji post ie http://toronto.en.craigslist.ca/tor/atq/3346994296.html:

1. email address (default one provided by craigslist)
2. items in the post
3. address of poster

Above 1-3 is information that can be manually obtained but would like to just input a posting or ad ID and be able to extract this info.

Comment: Please, clarify. You'd like to get:  1. the email addr. ie. the one starting w/ `gdqzg-3346994296@sale....`, 2. the title of the post, i.e. `Antique Radio & Record Player-Westinghouse 1939~1957 - $125 (Scarborough)` Right?   As for the 3. Address of Poster... hum I don't seem to find that info on the example web page provided....  ?

Comment: Hi thanks for trying to help with my question.  I would like to extract information from a typical ad or post on cragslist.  The information I want is the email address (the default email im hoping is possible), items in the ad and the address/location of the poster.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer to this question is...
Yes, automatically extracting the info listed from web pages similar to the one provided as example can be done by a relatively simple script.

In general, this activity [of automatically extracting info from web pages] is known as *Web Scraping*, a particular form of [***Data Scraping***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_scraping).
There are both off-the-shelf products that can be used (no or little programming involved; the parametrization of the desired pages and desired fields within the pages is specified by way of configuration.),  as well as software libraies which can be used in relation with scripting languages such as python or java and which facilitate the parsing of HTML page, and more generally provide support for the various tasks associated with this activity.

Aside from technical considerations, you need to assert the etiquette and legality of performing this kind of scraping.  Whereby some data and sites may be explicitly copyright-protected, it is always a good idea to perform big scraping jobs at low traffic hours and by throttling the requests as to not burden the host site unduly.  Also many sites may provide an API or data dumps to supply the same info in a simpler and more controlled fashion.

Comment: thanks for all the helpful information.  I needed to know if it was possible to scrape the info i needed from a ad posting.  I am pretty certain craigslist or kijiji does not have apis for what i am looking for.